# Creating a space between flex items in nested flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a nested flex box structure how ever there is no gap between the flex item.

```
      <div class = "navbar-container">
      <a href="index.html">
        <div class = "logo">
          <img src="./media/logo.svg" alt = " logo" height = "80px" width="80">
        </div>
      </a>
      <ul class = "nav-links">
        <li class = "nav-link">
          <a href="#">Install</a>
        </li>
        <li class = "nav-link">
          <a href="#">Learn</a>
        </li>
        <li class = "nav-link">
          <a href = "#">item</a>
        </li>
        <li class = "nav-link">
          <a href = "#">item</a>
        </li>

        <li class = "nav-link">
           <a href="#">item</a>
        </li>
        
      </ul>
  </div>
```

In my css body, I tried using `justify-content` property but it just does not work.

```
.navbar-container{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
 }
 .nav-links{
   display: flex;
   justify-content:space-between;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set Width of nav-links or use column-gap

```css
        .navbar-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: space-around;
        }
        .nav-links {
            width: 300px;
            // column-gap: 30px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
   
</head>

<body>

    <div class="navbar-container">
        <a href="index.html">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="./media/logo.svg" alt=" logo" height="80px" width="80">
            </div>
        </a>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li class="nav-link">
                <a href="#">Install</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-link">
                <a href="#">Learn</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-link">
                <a href="#">item</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-link">
                <a href="#">item</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-link">
                <a href="#">item</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `column-gap: 35px;` in `.nav-links` class. [Read this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-gap.asp)

OR

You can add `padding-left:35px;` in `li.nav-link`.

```css
.nav-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    column-gap: 35px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to restructure a big portion of code for a client because I had built many of the components on the website with `gap` in `flex`-structures, and they were using a browser that **didn't** support it.

`gap` has support in all modern browsers for `flex`, but not as great as `gap` for `grid` for some reason. Hopefully it will have full support soon.

`flex-gap` support: https://caniuse.com/?search=flex-gap

`grid-gap` support: https://caniuse.com/?search=grid-gap

For that reason alone, I would also like to suggest a solution that achieves the same with `padding-right`. You will most likely get by fine by using `gap` though. The code below will give `padding` to all the `nav-link`-elements besides the last one.

```css
.navbar-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav-link:not(:last-child) {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-container">
  <a href="index.html">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="./media/logo.svg" alt=" logo" height="80px" width="80">
    </div>
  </a>
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li class="nav-link">
      <a href="#">Install</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link">
      <a href="#">Learn</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link">
      <a href="#">item</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link">
      <a href="#">item</a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-link">
      <a href="#">item</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```